# $rootScope in callback is not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple app with firebase. To firebase database I save some data, and after saving I want to show alert window to user with response that "everythig is great" or "bad". For alert window I using ui-bootstrap. For alert I using $rootScope. So when I saved some data I have callback:

```
person.child(someName)
                  .set(personData)
                  .then(function () {
                    $rootScope.alert = {type:'success', msg:'Person is added!'};
                      $rootScope.showAlert = true;
                    console.log($rootScope.showAlert, $rootScope.alert);
                   })
                   .catch(function (e) {
                     $rootScope.alert = {type:'danger', msg:e};
                     $rootScope.showAlert = true;
                   });
```

html is:

```
  <div uib-alert
     ng-class="'alert-' + (alert.type || 'warning')"
     dismiss-on-timeout="2000"
     ng-if="showAlert"
     close="close()">{{alert.msg}}
</div>

<button ng-click='press()'>Press</button>
```

and controller calls a factory:

```
$scope.press = function() {
  fact.setItem({name: 'Josh', age: 20, sex: 'male'});
}
```

In console I see that rootScope is setup value for alert and showAlert, but alert is not working, so I bind this 2 value in html page, and I see that my first press the button is not working, but second is working and etc. [In jsbin example I make this situation](https://jsbin.com/litejucaqa/2/edit?html,js,output). Where I'm wrong in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since firebase is the third party to angular, `$rootScope` is not getting applied.

So, you have to manually apply the `$rootScope` to make it work.

HEre is one solution for your problem. and I will try to find another solution to it soon.

Try making your factory to,

```
app.factory('fact', ['$firebaseArray', '$rootScope', function($firebaseArray, $rootScope) {
  var person = firebase.database().ref().child('evil_genius');

  return {

    setItem : function(personData) {
       var someName = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
                return person.child(someName)
                  .set(personData)
                  .then(function () {
                    $rootScope.alert = {type:'success', msg:'Person is added!'};
                      $rootScope.showAlert = true;
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                    console.log($rootScope.showAlert, $rootScope.alert);
                   })
                   .catch(function (e) {
                     $rootScope.alert = {type:'danger', msg:e};
                     $rootScope.showAlert = true;
                   });
    }
  }
}])
```

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/tefoviguza/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: thx for answer, it works! I forgot about $apply and several days can't understand whats wrong with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.then(function () {
    $rootScope.alert = {type:'success', msg:'Person is added!'};
    $rootScope.showAlert = true;
    $rootScope.$apply();
})
.catch(function (e) {
    $rootScope.alert = {type:'danger', msg:e};
    $rootScope.showAlert = true;
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```